# Youtube Iframe video not autoplay on IOS and some android devices browsers

Tags: android, ios, iframe, web, youtube

I integrate `youtube video` on my website through an iframe. It works good start playing(autoplay) when page load on browsers.

But it shows issues when I run it on browsers of **IOS** and some **android devices**.

Either IOS does not allow autoplay video or is there any other issue?

Here is [link](https://www.youtube.com/embed/fzl8kE2pzYQ?autoplay=1&loop=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fksa.yallamotor.com&widgetid=1) to iframe.

Comment: How to run in android or iOS ,direct open youtube video URL in webview ? please share your webview code for android

Comment: @please share your code for iOS.

Comment: its not IOS code.... its html code

Comment: Basically iframe video not autoplay on IOS browsers and android devices browsers